# code not running as aspected given wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print

```
A

B C

C D E

E F G H
```

I tried but showing the result

```
A 

B C 

C D D 

D E E E 


a = chr(65)
for i in range(0, 4):
    i = i + 1
    for j in range(65, 65+i):
        print(a, end=" ")
        a = chr(65 + i)
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple:

```
letter_a_code = ord('A')
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(i+1):
        letter = chr(letter_a_code+j+i)
        print(letter, end=" ")
    print()
```

prints:

```
A 
B C 
C D E 
D E F G
```

You have to print 4 rows. `i` is your index.
Each row is made of `i` elements.

Add the offset for letter `A` code (don't hardcode it, use `ord('A')`): done.

Comment: I liked the previous solution better. Was very simple and elegant.

Comment: I used `ord('A')` to avoid hardcoding 65. I could have used a variable instead. Editing